# Save to Database with Filters

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working on a project, which I have to save a photo in the database with the filters applied, but it only saves the original and with those of the filters it gives "error". I already created a column in the table of images with the name of "filter", follow the code I have already done.

```
$("#ztier-savecopy").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveCopy", "Library")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                ID : @Model.ID,
                JsonTools: JSON.stringify(lc.getSnapshot(['shapes'])),
                Base64Image: lc.getImage().toDataURL(),
                //NuResolutionWidth: $("#ztier-tools-container").attr("width").replace("px",""),
                //NuResolutionHeight: $("#ztier-tools-container").attr("height").replace("px","")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Sucesso");
                $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Uma cópia da imagem foi salva com sucesso!");
                $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Erro");
                $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Não foi possível salvar uma cópia da imagem!");
                $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });

    $("#ztier-savefilter").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("SaveFilter", "Library")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 
                ID: @Model.ID,
                Base64Image: lc.getImage().toDataURL(),
                Filter: getValues(), 
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Sucesso");
                $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Uma cópia da imagem foi salva com sucesso!");
                $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
            },
            error: function () {
                $('#ztier-modal-title').text("Erro");
                $('#ztier-modal-message').text("Não foi possível salvar uma cópia da imagem");
                $('#ztierModalMessage').modal('show');
            }
        });
    });,
```

Comment: Please put in more details. Is the error on the server side or the client side?  What is the error message? Stacktrace if any?

Comment: the error is on the client side, when it clicks save, it gives the error function. the getValues function, takes the result of the filters in the image